# VB.Net falls over INTERVAL DAY(2) field type

Tags: sql, vb.net, odbc, hp-nonstop

I have an application written in VB.NET that collects information from an SQL/MX database via an ODBC driver. All works fine except for one specific table that contains two INTERVAL DAY(2) fields. When I run the query for this table I get an 'Unknown SQL type -  103' error. If change my query to exclude these fields then it works fine.

```
Dim SQLQueryDataAdapter As New OdbcDataAdapter(MySQLQuery, MyNonStopConnection)
Dim SQLQueryOutputTable As New DataTable("SQLOutput")
SQLQueryDataAdapter.Fill(SQLQueryOutputTable)
```

My ODBC connection string:

```
MyNonStopConnection = New OdbcConnection(
        "Driver=" & MyDriver & ";DSN=" & MyDSN & ";SERVER=TCP:" _
        & MyTCP & ";UID=" & MyUserName & ";PWD=" & MyPassword)

MyNonStopConnection.Open()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not all data types get through ODBC correctly (depending upon flavour of SQL and driver). You may need to `CAST` the fields in question as a more standard type.
What driver are you using?

Comment: I doubt that is something to do with the ODBC. Initially I used Excel(VBA) and the same ODBC driver to collect the information. Then it went without any problems.

Comment: I am using SQL/MX 3.1 driver

Answer (score 0):

What is the MAXIMUM number of days you expect to log as the INTERVAL?

To me it looks like either your precision or data type length is incorrect for your SQL Interval Field? so one would be tempted to ask how you defined the field type? in your table record.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716230(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I INVOKE the table then this is defined:   ,TOES_RESV_DGN_AANT               INTERVAL DAY(2) NO DEFAULT